# Define custom width only to the 1st column of DataGridView after AutoSizeColumns and AutoSizeRows

Tags: winforms, datagridview, resize

I have a **DataGridView** in my **WinForms** project that is working fine.

I set these properties to it

[image]

And it size the Columns and the Rows perfectly fine. I would like to ask, how to make bigger my 1st column than the others?

This is what I'm trying to do

```
myDataGridView.Columns[1].Width = 400;
```

But I don't when the event `autosize` raises, so I put this code after it.

Edit:

This is how my DataGridView looks like.

[image]

As you can see all my columns are the same size that's because of the property **AutoSizeColumnsMode Fill** and **AutoSizeRowsMode AllCells**, I would like just to make the 1st column bigger than the others.

When I try to do:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;

myDataGridView.Columns[1].Width = 400;
```

I got the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Reference to an object not set on an object instance.'

Comment: The first column should be index `0`, rather than `1`. And could you explain last sentence in detail?

Comment: I will update the question posting another image so maybe it would be more clear. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add `myDataGridView.Columns[0].Width = 400;` to `Form_Load` or after `InitializeComponent();` which in `Form constructor`.

Just like,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new DataTable.
    DataTable table = new DataTable("TestTable");
    DataColumn column;
    DataRow row;

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.ColumnName = "id";
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    column.ColumnName = "name";
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["id"] = i;
        row["name"] = "name " + i;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 400;
}
```

Or,

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 400;
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Reference to an object not set on an object instance`

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 400;` This one

Comment: @ChangeWorld Could you provide more info about `myDataTable`? And I have updated my answer with a datatable. You can check if it works.